# Azure deployed bot does not respond back

Tags: azure, botframework

I have deployed a bot on Azure and its deployed to the web channel. I am using it through a website. It was also working through the web link a few hours back and now it does not. I didn't change the code or any settings in the services.

I am using node.js code and QnA maker services. Individual services are up and running.

Can someone help me what shall I tweak to access the bot from the web link again?

Thanks,
Vivek Jain

Comment: Hi Vivek! There are a number of things that can cause this to happen. What errors are you getting in the channel list under 'Web Chat'? When you say 'stops responding', what shows in the web chat box? Is it "cannot send, Retry?". Alternatively, what shows on your developer console when you try to connect with the bot?

Comment: Can you add Application Insights to your bot, publish it again, and then turn on Live Metric Stream in the Azure Portal to see if your message is being received by your bot?